# FileExists() returns false, even if file exists

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007

I want to check if a dll in System32 directory (Windows 7) exists. But even if it exists, FileExists() returns false. LoadLibrary returns a valid handle. 
In this case, I only want to check, if the files exists and visualize this information.
Do you have a any tips to solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing "permissions" issue.  Vista/Windows 7 is very protective about letting people muck around in \windows :)

Comment: @paulsm4: No, that can't be it. Windows will always let you find out if a file exists or not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most likely this is down to file redirection. You have a 64 bit machine but from the 32 Delphi process, `Windows\system32` actually redirects to `Windows\Syswow64`. So when you think you are asking for the existence of a file in `Windows\system32`, the system is actually reporting the existance (or otherwise) of a file in `Windows\Syswow64`.

If you really do need to see into the true 64 bit system32 then you need to disable file redirection. You can do this with the [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Don't forget to switch it back on with [`Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection()`](http://Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection). Beware that disabling the redirector has wide reaching effects and can result in very strange behaviour so do so with care.

Comment: This is more like it. (Well, this and some silly typo, of course...)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I am 99 % this is the problem. +1, definitely.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the case, in the past I had something similar, the strange was that my total commander showed me the redirected folder too, after somebody told me it's because it is 32bit everything was clear.(you can still disable redirection there). Anyway just checked the TC site, now there's a 64bit beta.

Comment: You can use the special "Sysnative" alias to access the 64-bit System32 folder without disabling filesystem redirection, eg: `FileExists('C:\Windows\Sysnative\filename.dll')`

Comment: @Remy This is a good point, but if you wish to support XP 64 then you need to make sure that the relevant hotfix is installed.

Comment: @David: if he is trying to access an actual file in "C:\Windows\System32" on a **64 bit** system in order to **load the library**, it might actually make sense that it *shouldn't* work, as the file is very likely a **64 bit DLL**.

Answer (score 10):

Not much information to go on, the code you are using might help, but could this be a 64 bit issue and that the dll is actually in the SysWOW64 folder? See [here](http://blogs.sepago.de/helge/2008/04/20/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-7/) for a good description of the how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost certainly not specifying the full or valid relative path of the file in your `FileExists` call.  `LoadLibrary` will search certain locations (those where dlls are expected to reside) for you, but `FileExists` will not.  Supply the complete and correct path and `FileExists` will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most ridiculous reason, but if it can help just one person...

Make sure you didn't accidentally name the file `something.dll.dll`.

I just had a situation where I installed an application on a clients computer, and then the application couldn't find `config.txt` located in the same directory. This had been working fine on other computers, so of course I was stumped.

Turns out the "show file extensions" setting was turned off on this clients computer, and the file had actually been named `config.txt.txt`... in my defence, I spend 90% of the time on OSx, and 9.99% on my own Windows system, with "show file extensions" enabled since ages ago.