# FileExists on Windows 64 and UAC - Any new solution?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using Windows 64 bit with UAC and need to check if a file exists in Windows System folder, without elevating privileges. Already searching for a solution in the last 6 hours, without success... :(

According to this question [FileExists() returns false, even if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627331/fileexists-returns-false-even-if-file-exists), I could use Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(), but I saw in many other places it is not recommended.

Now I am trying to use the special "Sysnative" alias, but when using with FileExists funcion, it doesn't work (for example: If fileexists('C:\Windows\Sysnative\dfrgui.exe') then ... )

Please, can someone help me with this? Maybe an Assembler (Asm) solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Your viable options are Sysnative or a 64 bit process. And note that UAC is not relevant at all. Nor is elevation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I found this ASM function http://www.delphigroups.info/2/f3/8976.html, but it doesn´t work here (Windows 7). About UAC, I made tests here and when execute application as admin, the "filexists" function works, but not when the permissions are limited. Thanks!

Comment: Again, how would some ASM from 2002 help? Do you have any reason to believe it will, or are you just thrashing about wildly? Secondly, why does UAC and elevation matter. Is the problem one of the file system redirector, or is the problem something else? I have a strong feeling that you have not diagnosed the problem correctly. Not least because dfrgui.exe is present in both 32 and 64 bit system directories. The bottom line is that in order to solve a problem you have to understand it. At the moment you have no idea what the problem really is. Asking a question is premature.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, but if I knew all these answers, maybe it was not necessary to ask the question :) Indeed I made a mistake, the path C:\Windows\Sysnative\dfrgui.exe was only an example, and works when used with sysnative, but I am checking a file in a folder the software creates, something like this: c:\windows\syswow64\test\file.dll. And, sorry again, I do not have any idea why sysnative works in the first example, but not with the path c:\windows\sysnative\test\file.dll. Do you?

Comment: Please describe the real problem. Where is the file. What bitness is your program. What is your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, question is tagged Delphi7 so we can safely assume 32 bit? ;)

Comment: @Paruba Your fundamental problem is that you are thrashing about trying things at random without thinking hard enough. As an exercise you really should try to determine, and write down, exactly what the problem is. That will help you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are right (as always)... :) When I found this strange behavior, I (completely lost my mind and) try to find a solution before analise the problem completely... Well, the check inside "system32" folder didn´t work. I will do a video to show what is happening here, maybe (or most probably) you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[Sysnative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(VS.85)) should work and is the most appropriate solution.

Quote from MSDN:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by
>   substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64
>   recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file
>   system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and
>   easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file
>   system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the
>   Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

small demo (Delphi XE - W7 x64):

```
program SO22990909;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
 STR_SYSNATIVEPATH = 'c:\windows\sysnative\';
 STR_SYSTEM32PATH = 'c:\windows\system32\';
 STR_DETECTFILE = 'wups2.dll';

procedure CheckFile(Filename : String);
begin
 if FileExists(Filename) then
   Writeln(Format('file %s found', [Filename]))
  else
   Writeln(Format('file %s not found', [Filename]));
end;


begin
  try
   CheckFile(STR_SYSTEM32PATH+STR_DETECTFILE);
   CheckFile(STR_SYSNATIVEPATH+STR_DETECTFILE);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
 ReadLn;
end.
```

**Program output (file exists only in c:\windows\system32):**

[image: program output:]

with file dfrgui.exe (file exists in c:\windows\system32 AND in c:\windows\syswow64):

[image: dfrgui]

Comment: WhosRDaddy thanks but it doesn´t work in my Delphi 7 :) I mean, the code compiles, but I have the same problem...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I did more tests here and your example works. But the path C:\Windows\Sysnative\dfrgui.exe was only an example, I need to check something like this c:\windows\syswow64\test\file.dll, but doesn´t work like the example. Please, do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: that is the redirected path, use the system32 directory (see David's answer), my example should work with your file...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments your file is

```
c:\windows\syswow64\test\file.dll
```

That is in the 32 bit system directory. Test for its existence with

```
FileExists('c:\windows\system32\test\file.dll')
```

You will benefit from reading carefully the [MSDN documentation on WOW64 file system redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).